# How to predict or forecast in transfer function model?

Tags: forecasting

Is there any way to predict a transfer function model by using predict() (or else) in R? I'm searching the package to do forecasting in transfer function model, but couldn't find one.

Comment: You couldn't find because there is no good transfer function capability in $R$

Comment: @forecaster Then, what should I do if I want to do it manually? I'm still confused about which formula I should used. Thanks

Comment: You could start reading forecasting book by box, Jenkins and reinsert and then start doing it manually, else look for commercial software like SAS/SPSS/Autobox

Comment: interestingly, @forecaster has answered a different question which is a direct answer to yours. it is still manual though. I guess he wants you to try first. here's the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169564/arimax-prediction-using-forecast-package)